# How to import csv file to POSTGRESQL when csv file in the same server on plpython3u?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, import

> ERROR: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.

i have this error when i tried to execute data from csv file

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_00.file()
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpython3u'
AS $BODY$
import pandas as pd

plan = pd.read_csv('/path/file.csv')
plan.columns = ['division',
                'deposit',
                'credits',
                'credit_cards',
                'med_cards',
                'smart_cards',
                'pidtrumka_cards',
                'curr_cash',
                'fop',
                'travel_risk',
                'green_card',
                'armour_protect',
                'doc_online',
                'service_ua',
                'empty1',
                'empty2',
                'empty3',
                'empty4',
                'empty5']
print(plan)
$BODY$;
```

i tried to execute data from csv file, as a result i have an error, i want to import data in the table on DB

Comment: 1) If the CSV file is where the Postgres server user can reach it and has privileges on it then use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) and `plpgsql`. 2) Otherwise use the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module 3) Is `/path/file.csv` actually a properly formatted CSV file? As the error implies it is not. In other words can you read it outside Postgres?

Comment: 1) i know that i can use copy, but it has other problems and in my situation  i need to use python
2) i will try csv module, but if you have any other idea it would be great
3) yes, it is properly formatted

Comment: Using `csv` directly will move the data the data quicker then running through Pandas, saves the conversion to a dataframe and then out of dataframe for whatever you want to do with the data.